# BackStage API swagger.json

Tags: backstage

For BackStage APIs, is there a way to get swagger.json file?

We want to host BackStage Front End as Azure Static Web App and Backend on Azure Kubernetes Service.

Then from Front End, we like to make calls to BackStage API. We like this BackStage API to be behind Azure API Management Gateway.

How can I get a swagger.json for BackStage APIs so that I can create proxy in Azure APIM?

Answer (score 1):

Got confirmation from various places that there is no swagger.json and there is no guarantee that participating plugins will make any now or in future.

We are manually creating the proxy in API Management based on endpoints we know and when we discover new, we add it to API proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing available.

What you can do, and I believe it doesn't suit your scenario, is to query the API calls in the Backstage backend.